# How do I fix the cross browser compatibility for my CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: css, sass, grid, cross-browser, css-grid

I have successfully created a CSS Grid layout. However, now I want to add support or a fallback for non or poorly supported browsers, specifically IE11.

I have added browser prefixes and read a million articles about adding floats, etc. I created a block of code that should work, but I cannot for the life of me get it to render when testing on IE11 (I have a Mac laptop with no access to a PC).

```py
// sass-lint:disable no-important no-vendor-prefixes no-duplicate-properties final-newline

// Grid Variables
$cols: 12 !default;
$gutter: 50px !default;

// Breakpoints
$lg: 1199.98px;
$md: 991.98px;
$sm: 767.98px;
$xs: 575.98px;

$breakpoints: (
  (l, $lg, 100%, 1),
  (m, $md, 100%, 2),
  (s, $sm, 100%, 2),
  (x, $xs, 100%, 3),
  (no, 0, 100%, 3)
) !default;

// Typography
$font-size: 20px;
$font-family: 'BrokenEn', serif;
$line-height: 1.4;

// Animations
$grid-animation: all .15s ease-in-out;
$grid-animation-slow: all .3s ease-in-out;

// Globals

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #000;
  font: normal 1rem $font-family;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

// Grid
header,
main,
footer {
  background-color: #f5f5dc;
  width: 100%;
}

.r {
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #7fffd4;
  display: -ms-grid !important;
  display: grid !important;
  grid-gap: $gutter;
  grid-template-columns: repeat($cols, 1fr);
  position: relative;
  transition: $grid-animation;
}

[class*='c-'] {
  -ms-grid-column-span: $cols;
  background-color: #faebd7;
  grid-column: span $cols;
  position: relative;

  &.nest {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    background-color: #7fffd4;
    display: -ms-grid !important;
    display: grid !important;
    grid-gap: $gutter;
    grid-template-columns: repeat($cols, 1fr);
    position: relative;
  }

  &.contain-auto {
    margin-left: $gutter;
    margin-right: $gutter;
  }

  &.contain-fixed {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: $lg;
  }
}

.col-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 $gutter;
  width: 100%;
}

.no-c-gap {
  grid-column-gap: 0 !important;
}

@for $i from 1 through $cols {
  .c-#{$i} {
    -ms-grid-column-span: $i;
    grid-column: span $i;
  }
}

@each $name, $size, $container, $divide in $breakpoints {
  @media only screen and (max-width: $size) {
    .r {
      grid-gap: $gutter / $divide;
    }

    [class*='c-'] {
      &.nest {
        grid-gap: $gutter / $divide;
      }

      &.contain-auto {
        margin-left: $gutter / $divide;
        margin-right: $gutter / $divide;
      }
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $cols {
      .#{$name}#{$i} {
        -ms-grid-column-span: $i;
        grid-column: span $i;
      }
    }
  }
}

@supports not (display: grid) {
  .r {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 100% !important;

    ::after {
      content: ' ';
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    [class*='c-'] {
      display: block !important;
      float: left !important;
      margin: 0 $gutter $gutter 0;
    }
  }

  @for $i from 1 through $cols {
    .c-#{$i} {
      width: calc((100% / #{$cols} * #{$i}) - #{$gutter}) !important;
    }
  }

  @each $name, $size, $container, $divide in $breakpoints {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $size) {
      @for $i from 1 through $cols {
        .#{$name}#{$i} {
          width: calc((100% / #{$cols} * #{$i}) - #{$gutter}) !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// If @support not supported by browser.
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  .r {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 100% !important;

    ::after {
      content: ' ';
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    [class*='c-'] {
      display: block !important;
      float: left !important;
      margin: 0 $gutter $gutter 0;
    }
  }

  @for $i from 1 through $cols {
    .c-#{$i} {
      width: calc((100% / #{$cols} * #{$i}) - #{$gutter}) !important;
    }
  }

  @each $name, $size, $container, $divide in $breakpoints {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $size) {
      @for $i from 1 through $cols {
        .#{$name}#{$i} {
          width: calc((100% / #{$cols} * #{$i}) - #{$gutter}) !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone help me look over the code and tell me how I can (1) better my grid, (2) get the "@supports not (display: grid)" code to work in IE11?

EDIT:

This would be an example of how it looks in all modern browsers, and how I would want it to look after the IE fallback kicks-in.

[image: How it should look with IE fallback script]

```
<body>
    <header class="r">Header</header>
    <main class="r">
        <section class="c-12 nest ratio-4-3">
            <div class="c-6">
                <div class="wrap">Div Left</div>
            </div>
            <div class="c-6">
                <div class="wrap">Div Left</div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="c-12 nest no-c-gap ratio-4-3">
            <div class="c-6">
                <div class="wrap">Div Left</div>
            </div>
            <div class="c-6">
                <div class="wrap">Div Left</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="r">Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you edit to include a picture of the layout you're trying to accomplish? If so we could recommend a different solution.

Comment: @BryceHowitson - I have updated the post with all the new code and an image. Would you maybe suggest adding flex as a fallback instead of inlines and floats? How would you go about achieving this simply?

Comment: What does it need to do on mobile? And does the content need to be equal height? `float` is the most widely supported and `flex-box` would be next.

Comment: @BryceHowitson - On mobile, they would stack. I can figure out the responsive part secondary based on the desktop code alterations. I really only want to support IE11, and, I will put a message to upgrade the browser for everything below IE11. You can see I started with the floats, but it just does not render properly or close to the picture in IE and I cannot seem to get it to work, so I am happy to use flex if needed. I love the CSS grid code, so really just need updates and suggestions on the "@support" section down.

Answer (score 1):

1. `@supports` isn't [supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=supports) So you have to put code in there for browsers that DO support grid. It should override your NON-Grid code. (remove the "not").
2. Grid is only [partly supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid) in IE so you're likely better off using a [polyfill](https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/) for support over the partial options in the browser.
3. If you need to do a lot of cross-browser testing, look into a tool like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/).

---

*Edit: to suggest a course of action.*

**I suggest this approach.**

Re-write everything using a layout technique other than `CSS Grid`. People have been making cross-browser, performant, responsive layouts for years without grid. This will likely work across ALL your target browsers. If at this point, you get something better by using CSS Grid, use it as progressive enhancement.

The reason, I suggest this is a different layout technique might require additional containers/wrappers forcing your markup to change. It will be difficult to add these in, only "when grid won't work".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. All of the articles I have read warn against polyfill for speed, and because most of the ones out there are not relevant or working properly anymore. The articles are all saying to use floats, etc to add support. I will def look into the @support tag.

Comment: Well, I think the argument is really this: *"It must look/function the same in all browsers"* then use a polyfill. You lose performance but get to keep the same structure and code. If it can format/work differently depending on support then code it the way we used to before grid/flexbox using floats or even tables...

Comment: Found this gem - If "@support" needed for IE10+ ... @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}

Comment: Good answer, specially point number 1. You don't need "@suppor"t for IE. Just invert the logic, as stated in point 1 in the answer. Put the old styles first, and then in a *@support* set the grid styles. For browsers that don't support "@support", the first styles will apply